# How can i update my JSON data in Post man?

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, typescript, postman

> I am working on the typescript and mysql rest api, here i am storing
> data as json in database i could do inserted api but i couldn't
> updated which i stored as json , here i have attached my api.

```
const updateFooterGeneral = async (componentId: string, data: any) => {
    const connection = await createConnection()
    console.log(data)

    try {
        await connection.beginTransaction()
       
        let sqlQuery = `UPDATE component_localization SET json_content=?,updated_date=? WHERE component_id = ?`
        let params = [data.jsonContent, moment().format(), componentId]
        let component:any = await connection.execute(sqlQuery, params);
console.log(component)
        
        
        
        return component;

    } catch (error) {
        await connection.rollback()
        throw error
    }
}
```

> Below are my postman json data how i have given in postman,

```
{
   "componentId": "50",
   "updated_date":"2023-01-13 08:14:16",
  "jsonContent": "{{column1: {“logo of channel”:”http://localhost:3004/public/uploads/companylogos/companyLogo-1671176064887.png",
              “telephone number” : "+39 0471 155 1350”,“adress of company”:”Handwerkerzone 12,Kaltern,Südtiro”,“mail_address”:”nfo@karriere-suedtirol.com”},column2:{“for candidates”:”Für Kandidaten”,value1:{“All jobs”:”Alle Jobs”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Companies”:”Firmen”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#” },value3:{“Talent coaching”:”Tolontberosune",
                 “link”:”http://localhost:3003/#"},
                 value4:{“Further education”:”Weiterbildung”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Career Hub”:”Karrier-Hub”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column3:{“For employers”:”Für Arbeitgeber”,value1:{“Products & prices”:”Produkte & Preise”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Corporate benefit”:”Corporate Benefit”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“My account”:”Mein Konto", “link”:”http://localhost:3003/#"}, value4:{“Support”:”Hilfebereich”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“HR-HUB”:”HR-Hub”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column4:{“About us”:”Über uns”,value1:{ “Team”:”Team”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Working for us”:”job bei uns,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“Partners”:”Partnerbereich",“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#"},value4:{“Support”:”Kontakt”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Contact”:”Hilfebereich”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column5:{“Others”:”Sonstiges”,value1:{“Imprint”:”Impressum”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Terms & conditions”:”AGBs”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“Privacy”:”Datenschutz",“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#" }, value4:{“Immo Südtirol”:”Immo südtirol”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Gastro Südtirol”:”Auto südtirol”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”}}}"
              
              
                 }
```

If i hit this data in postman i am getting error like this ,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token " in JSON at position 4
>   
>  at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at
> createStrictSyntaxError
> (/Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:160:10)
>    at parse
> (/Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
>    at
> /Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
>    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope
> (node:async_hooks:203:9)
>     at invokeCallback
> (/Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:231:16)
>    at done
> (/Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:220:7)
>    at IncomingMessage.onEnd
> (/Users/apple/Desktop/work1/clamsy/backend/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:280:7)
>    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:513:28)
>   
>  at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)

Answer (score 0):

jsoncontent is not valid string because of the misplaced quotes. try this

```
"jsonContent": "{{column1: {“logo of channel”:”http://localhost:3004/public/uploads/companylogos/companyLogo-1671176064887.png”,
              “telephone number” : ”+39 0471 155 1350”,“adress of company”:”Handwerkerzone 12,Kaltern,Südtiro”,“mail_address”:”nfo@karriere-suedtirol.com”},column2:{“for candidates”:”Für Kandidaten”,value1:{“All jobs”:”Alle Jobs”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Companies”:”Firmen”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#” },value3:{“Talent coaching”:”Tolontberosune”,
                 “link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},
                 value4:{“Further education”:”Weiterbildung”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Career Hub”:”Karrier-Hub”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column3:{“For employers”:”Für Arbeitgeber”,value1:{“Products & prices”:”Produkte & Preise”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Corporate benefit”:”Corporate Benefit”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“My account”:”Mein Konto”, “link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”}, value4:{“Support”:”Hilfebereich”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“HR-HUB”:”HR-Hub”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column4:{“About us”:”Über uns”,value1:{ “Team”:”Team”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Working for us”:”job bei uns,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“Partners”:”Partnerbereich”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value4:{“Support”:”Kontakt”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Contact”:”Hilfebereich”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},column5:{“Others”:”Sonstiges”,value1:{“Imprint”:”Impressum”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value2:{“Terms & conditions”:”AGBs”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value3:{“Privacy”:”Datenschutz”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#” }, value4:{“Immo Südtirol”:”Immo südtirol”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”},value5:{“Gastro Südtirol”:”Auto südtirol”,“link”:”http://localhost:3003/#”}}}
              
              
                 }"
```

Comment: Hi thanks, But if i give this jsonContent in my postman again same issue showing.